# Collate variable into a string @

Tags: c#

I have this text string and I need to change the user_con text to a variable

```
var data = @"{""AuthParameters"" : {
""USERNAME"" : ""user_con"",
""PASSWORD"" : ""passw_con""
},
""AuthFlow"" : ""USER_PASSWORD_AUTH"",
""ClientId"" : ""952m5bj""
}";
```

I can't find a way to insert the variable without errors

Comment: Maybe [this can help](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/string-interpolation#how-to-use-escape-sequences-in-an-interpolated-string).

Comment: Interpolated verbatim string: $@"""USERNAME"":""{userNameVariable}""";

Comment: Or create a Model for this JSON object, deserialize to Model, edit and serialize back to string

Answer (score 0):

```
string user_con = "value";

var data = @"{""AuthParameters"" : { ""USERNAME"" : """ + user_con + @""", ""PASSWORD"" : ""passw_con"" }, ""AuthFlow"" : ""USER_PASSWORD_AUTH"", ""ClientId"" : ""952m5bj"" }";
```

Comment: This could produce invalid JSON if the `user_con` variable contains a double quote `"` and potentially cause other issues.

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Answer (score 0):

It's usually a bad idea to hand-craft JSON like this as it's prone to errors.

A better idea would be to use a bespoke DTO or even an anonymous object at a push:

```cs
    var user_con = "user_name";

    var obj = new {
        AuthParameters = new {
            USERNAME = user_con,
            PASSWORD = "passw_con",
        },
        AuthFlow = "USER_PASSWORD_AUTH",
        ClientId = "952m5bj"
    };
    
    var data = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(obj);
```

This will guarantee that you end up with valid JSON.

Answer (score 0):

A bit mistaken with interpolated verbatim string example in comments, so posting as answer.

You can concatenate json string with variables, as @prekasi suggested.

Or you can use interpolation for verbatim string, which is look a bit messy:

```
public void Test()
{
     var userName = "user_con";
     var password = "passw_con";
     var authFlow = "USER_PASSWORD_AUTH";
     var clientId = "952m5bj";

     var data = $@"{{ ""AuthParameters"" : {{
             ""USERNAME"" : ""{userName}"",
             ""PASSWORD"" : ""{password}""
         }},
         ""AuthFlow"" : ""{authFlow}"",
         ""ClientId"" : ""{clientId}" 
     }}";
}
```

Both concatenation and interpolation has large risk to "broke" your JSON, if value from variable contains some unescaped JSON-syntax char.

So proper way, in my opinion, is to create a class, which will represent this JSON object. Then use serialization or deserialization to read from or write to JSON. This way you can be sure, that data will correctly be written to a JSON string.

Example below utilizes `System.Text.Json`:

```
    public class AuthorizationInfo
    {
        [JsonPropertyName("AuthParameters")] 
        public AuthorizationParameters AuthorizationParameters { get; set; } = new();
        [JsonPropertyName("AuthFlow")]
        public string AuthorizationFlow { get; set; }
        [JsonPropertyName("ClientId")]
        public string ClientIdentifier { get; set; }

        public static AuthorizationInfo FromJson(string json)
        {
            return JsonSerializer.Deserialize<AuthorizationInfo>(json);
        }

        public string ToJson()
        {
            return JsonSerializer.Serialize(this, new JsonSerializerOptions { WriteIndented = true });
        }
    }
    public class AuthorizationParameters
    {
        [JsonPropertyName("USERNAME")]
        public string Username { get; set; }
        [JsonPropertyName("PASSWORD")]
        public string Password { get; set; }
    }
```

And simply use it:

```
    public void Test()
    {
        var userName = "user_con";
        var password = "passw_con";
        var authFlow = "USER_PASSWORD_AUTH";
        var clientId = "952m5bj";
        
        var data = "your_json_string";

        var autorizationInfo = AuthorizationInfo.FromJson(data);
        if (autorizationInfo != null)
        {
            autorizationInfo.AuthorizationParameters.Username = userName;
            autorizationInfo.AuthorizationParameters.Password = password;
            autorizationInfo.AuthorizationFlow = authFlow;
            autorizationInfo.ClientIdentifier = clientId;

            var jsonAuthInfo = autorizationInfo.ToJson();
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you're replacing all the properties, what's the point of deserializing the JSON in the first place?

Comment: That's just example and demonstration of what (de)serializing is. How "ClientId" from string goes into "ClientIdentifier" property of some class on deserialize, and vice versa on serialize. You may compact it in a style you wish, if enough experienced)